# How can I parse an XML file stored in blobstore on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-parsing, blobstore

I need to parse an XML file stored in the blobstore. How do I do that?

This is  what I have done till now:

```
FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
AppEngineFile file = fileService.getBlobFile(new BlobKey(key));
```

I cannot parse the XML file using `javax.xml` package or can I? The classes in that package if put into action requires a reference of a `java.io.File` object. But I do not have that.

*This is what I have been doing till now :* (not on the server but locally)

```
         File blobKeys = new File("/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Personal Site_Testers/web/xml/xml_1.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(blobKeys);
        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

        Element firstName = doc.createElement("first-name");
        firstName.setTextContent(name);

        root.appendChild(firstName);

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("/home/non-admin/NetBeansProjects/Personal Site_Testers/web/xml/xml_1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

*Note : There are 3 xml files uploaded to the blobstore. Those xml files just have a root tag . I want to get the xml reference and parse them to append child node several times depending upon the request made.*

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/

Comment: @WimDeblauwe How will **that** help me ?

Comment: It was just something I found that might be useful in getting an actual File object. But I think the suggestion from @zsxwing is much better. You should use the FileService as he says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse *.xml, I think [jdom2](http://www.jdom.org/) may be is more convenient which I use in the app engine and it works.

However, you can read the [FileService](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService) API document and there is an example with how to read and write the file. If you can get a InputStream or Reader, then you can use javax.xml to parse the xml  content in the InputStream or Reader.

```
    FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
    AppEngineFile readableFile = new AppEngineFile("your_file_name");
    FileReadChannel readChannel = fileService.openReadChannel(readableFile,
            false);
    InputStream input = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(input);

    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();

    Element firstName = doc.createElement("first-name");
    firstName.setTextContent("content");

    root.appendChild(firstName);
    // Now write
    GSFileOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder()
            .setBucket("mybucket").setKey("myfile")
            .setMimeType("text/html").setAcl("public_read")
            .addUserMetadata("myfield1", "my field value"); // change as
                                                            // your need
    AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(optionsBuilder
            .build());
    FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
            writableFile, false);
    OutputStream output = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: I want to parse xml with high layer of abstraction that javax.xml offers when computing locally

Comment: Do you create the XML yourself as well? You might want to try [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) if you just want to serialize and deserialize objects to/from XML in a high level way

Comment: There are 3 xml files uploaded to the blobstore. Those xml files just have a root tag . Now I want to get the xml reference and parse them to append a child node. This is all I want to do.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to parse the xml file and append something to some nodes? What's the problem when you try to do it?

Comment: First, you can get a Reader of the xml file. Then, you use javax.xml APIs to parse the Reader. I think it's OK. What's error when you try to do like this?

Comment: I try to show a demo that how to use the FileService and javax.xml APIs.

Comment: Maybe you just need new FileInputStream(file)?

Comment: **Nothing gets written to the `xml` file in the blobstore when I try the above code.I check the blobstore and it same as before with the just a root tag.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16067/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-zsxwing)

Comment: I have posted some code there. Unable to identify what is going wrong. There are no error logs but the xml doesn't get written

Comment: can you please help me find what is wrong in the code posted @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16067/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-zsxwing